# Does $|A \cap B|+|C| = |A \cap C|+|B \cap C|$ conclude $A \cap B \subseteq C \subseteq A\cup B$?

Tags: combinations

Suppose $A,B,C$ are finite subsets of a universal set $\mathcal{M}$

Could someone infer from $|A \cap B|+|C| = |A \cap C|+|B \cap C|$ that

$A \cap B \subseteq C \subseteq A\cup B$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Draw a Venn diagram, name the 7 areas accordingly, understand what the equation means exactly. The equation says, 
$$C\setminus (A\cup B)= \emptyset$$
$$(A\cap B) \setminus C= \emptyset$$
For example :

[image: Venn Diagram]

$$|A\cap B|= AB+ABC$$
$$|C| = C+BC+AC+ABC$$
$$|A\cap C|= AC+ABC$$
$$|B\cap C|= BC+ABC$$
So, the equation means, $AC+BC+ABC+ABC=C+BC+AC+ABC+AB+ABC$, or, $AB+C=0$. So, indeed 
$$A\cap B\subseteq C \subseteq A\cup B$$